# grails 3 - push notification

Tags: push-notification, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

I need to implement push notification in my grails 3 project. I searched for a while and could not reach for any plugin/ documentation/ dependency for help.

It would be a great help if I can get a full documentation or any hint on how to implement push notification in grails 3.

**I have tried to add dependency of CometD and Event-Push, but in grails 3 it failed to download the dependency.**

Is there any way to integrate any of these?

Comment: I am using Grails 3.2.7, is there any plugins available for Apple push notificatins ?

Comment: Were you able to embed events push plugin in grails 3 application? Or any other approach to use notification mechanism in grails3?

Comment: RabbitMq have been used successfully in our system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Grails-Events-Push**

1. Events-push is a client-side events bus based on the superb portable push library Atmosphere and Grails platform-core plugin for events propagation/listening.
2. It simply allows your client to listen to server-side events and push data.
3. It uses WebSockets by default and falls back to use Comet if required (server not compliant, browser too old...). Events-push is a white-list broadcaster (client-side events scope is 'browser'). You will need to define which events can be propagated to the server by modifying the Events DSL to use 'browser' scope.

4.To register listeners from client, you will need to define them as well.

Git hub demo:
https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push

**OR**

**CometD Plugin**

https://grails.org/plugin/cometd

Hope this help you

Comment: I have tried to add dependency, but failed as these doesnt support grails 3 .

Comment: Please try to get proper version of this